# Missing constraints in ConstaintLayout

Tags: android, android-studio

i hope you help me solve this problem in Android Studio Canary using Kotlin 
when i try to drag an element to the BleuPrint screen it does not apear
and this message show up the one on the image below 
[image]

please help solve this problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error while using android studio 3.0 Alfa

I had the same problem and solved it by downgrading `com.android.support:appcompat` by one version

so use `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'`

instead of `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'`

and sync the project

Comment: it works now after your advice !! (:

Comment: then please mark my answer as accepted